# write_csv read_csv with scientific notation after 1000th row

Tags: r, tidyverse, scientific-notation, readr

Writing a data frame with a mix of small integer entries (value less than 1000) and "large" ones (value 1000 or more) into csv file with write_csv() mixes scientific and non-scientific entries.  If the first 1000 rows are small values but there is a large value thereafter, read_csv() seems to get confused with this mix and outputs NA for scientific notations:

```
test_write_read <- function(small_value, 
                            n_fills, 
                            position, 
                            large_value) {
    tib             <- tibble(a = rep(small_value, n_fills))
    tib$a[position] <- large_value
    write_csv(tib, "tib.csv")
    tib             <- read_csv("tib.csv")
}
```

The following lines do not make any problem:

```
tib <- test_write_read(small_value = 1, 
                       n_fills     = 1001, 
                       position    = 1000, #position <= 1000
                       large_value = 1000)
tib <- test_write_read(1, 1001, 1001, 999)
tib <- test_write_read(1000, 1001, 1000, 1)
```

However, the following lines do:

```
tib <- test_write_read(small_value = 1, 
                       n_fills     = 1001, 
                       position    = 1001, #position > 1000
                       large_value = 1000)
tib <- test_write_read(1, 1002, 1001, 1000)
tib <- test_write_read(999, 1001, 1001, 1000)
```

A typical output:

```
problems(tib)
## A tibble: 1 x 5
#  row   col   expected               actual file
#  <int> <chr> <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>
#1 1001  a     no trailing characters e3     'tib.csv'

tib %>% tail(n = 3)
## A tibble: 3 x 1
#      a
#  <int>
#1   999
#2   999
#3    NA
```

The csv file:

```
$ tail -n3 tib.csv
#999
#999
#1e3
```

I am running:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

with tidyverse_1.2.1 (loading readr_1.1.1)

Is that a bug that should be reported?

Comment: `read_csv` has an argument `guess_max`, which by default will be set to 1000. So `read_csv` only reads the first 1000 records before trying to figure out how each column should be parsed. Increasing `guess_max` to be larger than the total number of rows should fix the problem.

Comment: You could also specify `col_types=...` as double or character.

Comment: Using @CPak's suggestion will make your code more reproducible and your analyses more predictable in the long run. That's a primary reason `read_csv()` spits out a message about the colspec upon reading (so you can copy it and use it). Copy it, modify it and tell it to use a different type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed the dev version of readr:  `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/readr")`, so now I have readr_1.2.0, and the `NA` problem went away.  But the column "a" is "guessed" by `read_csv()` as `dbl` now (whether or not there is a large integer in it), whereas it was correctly read as `int` before, so if I need it as `int` I still have to do a `as.integer()` conversion.  At least now it does not crash my code.

```
tib <- test_write_read(1, 1002, 1001, 1000)
tib %>% tail(n = 3)
## A tibble: 6 x 1
#        a
#    <dbl>
#1    1.00
#2 1000
#3    1.00
```

The large value is still written as 1e3 by `write_csv()`, though, so to my opinion this is not quite a final solution.

```
$ tail -n3 tib.csv
#1
#1e3
#1
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the two answers, both correct, and the rationale as Community Wiki.

read_csv has an argument guess_max, which by default will be set to 1000. So read_csv only reads the first 1000 records before trying to figure out how each column should be parsed. Increasing guess_max to be larger than the total number of rows should fix the problem. – Marius 4 hours ago

You could also specify `,col_types= ...,` as double or character. – CPak 3 hours ago

Using @CPak's suggestion will make your code more reproducible and your analyses more predictable in the long run. That's a primary reason read_csv() spits out a message about the `colspec` upon reading (so you can copy it and use it). Copy it, modify it and tell it to use a different type.

Comment: Using `col_types = "d"` indeed works here on this minimal example, but this problem stemmed from a real life problem where I might not know in advance where this column might be.  Moreover I might need to keep the column as integer and then need an extra `mutate(a = as.integer(a))`.

Comment: I find the suggestion with `guess_max = ...` slightly more practical.  In my real life problem the data frame has typically between 10K and 100K rows and events with integer values > 1000 are rare.  There is no way to know in advance if the first such event will not occur after guess_max, unless I set guess_max to the number of rows.

Comment: What would solve completely this problem would be the `Allow int_use_scientific=FALSE` in write_csv from Zeehio [readr_commit](https://github.com/zeehio/readr/commit/9f4061269fb8b7a36d5f8d424ac54b093ec54c84) since there is really no need to write scientific notations automatically for integers >= 1000.

Comment: @Habert You can edit the answer. Might have more impact than a comment.